# find the first available long in a List<long>

Tags: c#, list, long-integer

ok, this should be interesting.

lets assume i have the following code:

in this example, the first available number would be `2`.

`List<long> myList = new List<long>(){0,1,10,3};`

in this example, the first available number would be '4'.

`List<long> myList = new List<long>(){0,1,2,3};`

any ideas?

Comment: Do the numbers always start from 0? Are you going to modify the list and ask for first available number later?

Comment: the numbers would allways start from zero, and the list will surely be modified later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So by "available" you mean "the lowest non-negative number which doesn't already exist in the list"?

I'd be tempted to write something like:

```
HashSet<long> existing = new HashSet<long>(list);
for (long x = 0; x < long.MaxValue; x++)
{
    if (!existing.Contains(x))
    {
        return x;
    }
}
throw new InvalidOperationException("Somehow the list is enormous...");
```

EDIT: Alternatively, you could order the list and then find the first value where the index isn't the same as the value...

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x);
var differences = ordered.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                         .Where(pair => pair.value != pair.index)
                         .Select(pair => (int?) pair.index);
var firstDifference = differences.FirstOrDefault();
long nextAvailable = firstDifference ?? list.Count;
```

The last line is to take care of the situation where the list is contiguous from 0. Another alternative would be:

```
var nextAvailable = list.Concat(new[] { long.MaxValue })
                        .OrderBy(x => x)
                        .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                        .Where(pair => pair.value != pair.index)
                        .Select(pair => pair.index)
                        .First();
```

This should be fine so long as the list doesn't contain `long.MaxValue + 1` elements, which it can't in current versions of .NET. (That's a lot of memory...) To be honest, this will already have problems when it goes beyond `int.MaxValue` elements due to the `Select` part taking an `int` index...

Comment: your second suggestion has an error on the last line, `??` cannot be applied in that case.

Comment: @Dementic: Fixed, thanks - I was using `FirstOrDefault` on the wrong expression.

Comment: at the end i used your 3rd methods, since i just love Lambda Linq.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.Sort();

var range = Enumerable.Range( list.First(), list.Last()- list.First());

var number = range.Except(list).FirstOrDefault();
```